mcmapply stalls with Rcpp/Armadillo function using openMP
I have issues with mcmapply that only occures if an Rcpp-function, testfun(), is first called outside mcmapply and then called through mcmapply. The issue only exists if:

testfun() uses openMP
mcmapply uses parallelization (mc.cores>1)

If I call mcmapply with testfun(), it runs and finishes without errors. If I first call testfun() separately and afterwards mcmapply, then mcmapply stalls.
MWE:
Rcpp::sourceCpp(code=
"  #include <RcppArmadillo.h>;
  // [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
  // [[Rcpp::export]]
  void testfun(int n) {
    arma::mat foo = arma::sqrt(arma::zeros(n,n));
  }")
library(parallel)

print("Run mcmapply+testfun: works")
mcmapply(mc.cores=2, function(x) testfun(100), 1:2)

print("Calling testfun separately: works")
testfun(100)

print("Run mcmapply+testfun after having run testfun separately: stalls")
mcmapply(mc.cores=2, function(x) testfun(100), 1:2)

It as to do with the use of openMP and I suspect the issue has to do with storing the matrices, as it only occurs if testfun() assigns the result of arma::sqrt() to an arma::mat. The issue does not appear if I specify #define ARMA_DONT_USE_OPENMP.
Setup: linux with R 4.4.0, gcc 14.2.0, and gsl 2.7.1, but issue also replicated on older R versions.

(Updated answer) It all works here if alter your example to actually compute something, and return a modified matrix.
Rcpp::sourceCpp(code=
"  #include <RcppArmadillo.h>;
  // [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
  // [[Rcpp::export]]
  arma::mat testfun(int n) {
    arma::mat foo = arma::sqrt(arma::randu(n,n));
    return foo;
  }")
library(parallel)

print("Run mcmapply+testfun: works")
set.seed(123)
mcmapply(mc.cores=2, function(x) testfun(5), 1:2)

print("Calling testfun separately: works")
set.seed(123)
testfun(5)

print("Run mcmapply+testfun after having run testfun separately: stalls")
set.seed(123)
mcmapply(mc.cores=2, function(x) testfun(5), 1:2)

Addendum: One reason for the stall you see could be that these *apply functions are not just launchers: they accumulate results. Yet your function did not return anything!
Addendum Two: As seen in the comments discussion, this turned out to be mcmapply() and its forked child processes being unhappy with the (implicit) OpenMP use by Armadillo (for large enough matrices).  The trick then is to define ARMA_DONT_USE_OPENMP.
(Initial answer) This violates the well-documented (see eg this post from a few days ago) rule that you cannot call back from parallel sections into R, or touch R objects.  For convenience and default, RcppArmadillo vectors and matrices use the R memory, and this violates it.  See the RcppParallel vignette for discussion, and its RVector and RMatrix classes for examples.

Thanks a lot for your answer. Do I understand you correctly that what you're saying is that using arma::mat basically constitutes using an object in R's memory which I shouldn't be touching from within mcmapply? So would switching to another matrix class solve the issue?

However, if my interpretation of what you said is correct, isn't it surprising that this only matters if openMP is used? It vanishes, e.g. if I replace arma::sqrt with arma::square

A different matrix class, as e.g. RMatrix in RcppParallell, forces a _copy_ of the data to non-R-management memory.  You can use an option to arma:mat` and friends to force that too but it is not the default.  And openMP is just one form of multithreading.  It may also depends what OS your own, Linux may be easiest here.

But I can replicate your stall too.  But something else may be going on.  Maybe try a real function on real (smaller, 10x10 ?) matrices and return it.

Just added this addendum:  One reason for the stall you see could be that these *apply functions are not just launchers: they accumulate results. Yet your function did not return anything!

Thanks for your thoughts, but that's not it. Three issue occurs with any type of return value.

But not for me in the counter example I posted.  I just ran it again.

Thanks for digging deeper, but sadly no. The counterexample just works because you've reduced n from 100 to 5. If the matrix worked on has less than 320 elements, Armadillo does not use openMP (ARMA_OPENMP_THRESHOLD), and this is what's why this is running through.

I see.  I would recommend trying to distill this into a C++ standalone example and if it persists as an issue submitting it at the Armadlllo repo.  I don't think R or Rcpp do anything here to inhibit how Armadillo loops under OpenMP.

Ok, I gave this some more thought and I think the problem is, sorry to say, still of your making.  When you invoke R's parallelism via mcmapply() it expects single-threaded performance.  But you invite OpenMP through the back door.  So I now have two working approaches:  one where we do as you did before but with #define ARMA_DONT_USE_OPENMP 1.  It works.  Or we can use what you had, run in parallel inside of the Armadillo calls ... but use lapply on the outside,  If you want both levels of parallelism, it seems you need more coordination.

It could be that the forking done by mcmapply conflicts with the OpenMP data structures.  That is just a guess on my part though.

Thanks again for your advice. For now I am going with #define ARMA_DONT_USE_OPENMP. I think I might be giving up on some performance here but I think it saves me a lot of time on debugging further.
